# If condition in LINQ for non-collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to take `ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value` amount products if `ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value == 0` I need to take all

```
var products = _dbProducts.GetAllDbSet()
            .Take(ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value)
            .Include(p => p.Supplier)
            .Include(p => p.Category)
            .AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: I suspect that your best bet will be to declare `products` variable (`IEnumerable<Product> products;`) and then have an if statement (`if (ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value == 0`) that calculates the value with and without the `Take` clause.  Note that you have a typo in `ProductMaxLenght`, you may want to rename it.

Comment: This question should include more details to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var products = _dbProducts.GetAllDbSet()
            .Include(p => p.Supplier)
            .Include(p => p.Category)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .AsEnumerable()
            .TakeWhile((product, i) => i < ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value 
                                        || ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var query = _dbProducts.GetAllDbSet()
            .Include(p => p.Supplier)
            .Include(p => p.Category)
            .AsNoTracking();
var takeCount=ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value;
if(takeCount >0) query = query.Take(takeCount);
var products=query.ToList();
```

Comment: I don't need take all object if it is not required

Comment: @DmitryChmel What it means " if Value == 0 I need to take all " then ?

Comment: It means take all if value == 0
Value is not a count of collection, it just a paramter